# How do you show a blue dot instead of a Pin when showing current location in mapview?

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, cllocationmanager, mkannotation, currentlocation

How do you show a blue dot instead of a Pin when showing current location in map view? at the moment the code illustrates a red pin that shows the users current location as the user moves around. How can i convert this to the blue dot that apple use?

```
  import UIKit
 import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myMapView: MKMapView!





let myLocMgr = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    myLocMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    myLocMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    myLocMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    myLocMgr.delegate = self

}



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        // get most recient coordinate
        let myCoor = locations[locations.count - 1]

        //get lat & long
        let myLat = myCoor.coordinate.latitude
        let myLong = myCoor.coordinate.longitude
        let myCoor2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myLat, longitude: myLong)

        //set span
        let myLatDelta = 0.05
        let myLongDelta = 0.05
        let mySpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: myLatDelta, longitudeDelta: myLongDelta)

        let myRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myCoor2D, span: mySpan)

        //center map at this region
        myMapView.setRegion(myRegion, animated: true)

        //add anotation
        let myAnno = MKPointAnnotation()
        myAnno.coordinate = myCoor2D
        myMapView.addAnnotation(myAnno)
    }



@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
    myLocMgr.stopUpdatingLocation()
}


@IBAction func resume(sender: AnyObject) {
    myLocMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

[`showsUserLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation) is what you need. It's [`MKMapView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapView) property set it in `viewDidLoad` or using IB (if possible). You don't need to do any extra stuff in `LocationManager`'s delegate `didUpdateLocations`, just set it the `MKMapView` will do the rest of the stuff